# Detox mocking: Trouble with Metro Bundler in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, detox, metro-bundler

So I've been following the documentation for [Detox mocking](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/guide/mocking/), and I have successfully gotten it to run locally. But only when I run `APP_MOCK=mocked npx react-native start`, so this means that when trying to create CI/CD with Github Actions, it starts the Metro bundler and hangs there,

like this.

[image: 2]

I've tried adding `APP_MOCK=mocked` to `react-native run-ios/android` but it just results in the mocked files not being loaded. My guess is that the `APP_MOCK=mocked` enviromental variable does not exist in the new terminal that the  Metro open.

So my question is this, can I add `APP_MOCK=mocked` to `react-native run-ios` and if yes, how? Or is it possible to programmatically open a new terminal in the same directory and then run the `APP_MOCK=mocked npx react-native start` script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was able to solve this by adding the mocked flag into the build command.
"MOCKED=mock detox build --configuration ios.sim.debug"

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question title or body. Great that you've solved your own question! Don't add it as a comment though; instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).